# How to handle quoted values in AWS Redshift unload command?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Suppose, following the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html) I'd like to use an unload command like

```
unload
(
'SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE day = '2019-01-01' 
')
to 's3://bucket_name/path' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws acct num>:role/<redshift role>'
ADDQUOTES
ESCAPE
DELIMITER ','
GZIP
ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

The problem is that the full query should be quoted and to write a string literal into the query will escape the string before the full query (as valid sql) is finished. How to escape quotes inside an AWS redshift unload statement?

Full disclosure, I know one way to do this but haven't seen a good link or SO question so figured I'd post one for others benefit.

Comment: What do you mean by "the full query should be quoted"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, what I mean is that the first single quote in the example given (immediately preceding the date => 2019-01-01 will escape the string literal when being parsed after submission by a client (e.g. SQLWorkbench and others). Then as parsed the query is not valid SQL (in this case would be  ```SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE day = ``` so you need to escape the single quotes around the date (or any other string literal) to get a valid SQL statement. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 20):

You can put the query between $$ symbols so that you don't have to worry about any kind of quotes

```
unload
(
$$SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE day = '2019-01-01' 
$$)
to 's3://bucket_name/path' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws acct num>:role/<redshift role>'
ADDQUOTES
ESCAPE
DELIMITER ','
GZIP
ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

Comment: you don't know how happy I am after 36 hours of headache - god bless you.

Comment: as always, aws documentation has no mention of this feature, i feel like aws should just stop whatever they are doing and just focus on improving their documentation

Answer (score 7):

From [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

> If your query contains quotes (for example to enclose literal values), put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must also enclose the query between single quotation marks:
>
> `('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')`

Comment: this is interesting, I had missed that on my last reading. I use a SQLWorkbench client at the office here in NYC. Another method which works for me is to escape the single quote with a backslash. e.g. ``` unload ('select * from venue where venuestate=\'NV\' ') ``` Which worked for me last week.