# Syntax error in Unload command in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

While I try to unload a data from spectrum table I am getting an syntax error:

> syntax error at or near "123"

```
unload('select *,
        **** (abc, \'123\') AS result123, 
        COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(***), ''),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle quoted values in AWS Redshift unload command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191070/how-to-handle-quoted-values-in-aws-redshift-unload-command)

Answer (score 2):

From [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

> If your query contains quotes (for example to enclose literal values), put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must also enclose the query between single quotation marks:
>
> `('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')`